# Getting "TypeError: db.createList is not a function"

Tags: postgresql, express, reactjs, massivejs

I am currently doing a React, Express, Massivejs, postgreSql app. I am getting the error "TypeError: db.createList is not a function" anytime I'm trying to hit my post endpoint. I'm not sure how to remedy it since it looks correct.

My file structure:

[image]

My server file looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cors = require('cors');
var massive = require("massive");
var connectionString = 'postgress://LonnieMcGill@localhost/todo';
var massiveInstance = massive.connectSync({connectionString : connectionString})
var config = require('./config.js');


var app = module.exports = express();
app.set('db', massiveInstance);

var listCtrl = require('./controller/listCtrl.js');

// **************** Middleware ****************
app.use(express.static(__dirname + './../public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// ****************** Endpoints ***************
app.post('/api/add/list', listCtrl.createList);
app.get('/api/get/list', listCtrl.createList);


app.get('*', function(req, res) {
res.sendFile('index.html', { root: './public'});
})

app.listen(config.port, function() { console.log('Server initiated on port', config.port); });
```

My controller looks like this:

```
var app = require('../server.js');
var db = app.get('db');

module.exports = {

    createList: function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('db'my);
        db.createList([req.body.name], function(err, res) {
            res.status(200).send('List created');
        })
    },

    readList: function(req, res) {
        db.readList(function(err, res) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("readList failed");
            } else {
                console.log("readList working " + req.body, req.params);
            }
         })
    }

}
```

My createList.sql file looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO list (
  name
)
VALUES (
   $1
);
```

Comment: Did you name the file "createlist.sql" or "createList.sql"?

Comment: Wrong image sorry. But I named it createList.sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The documentation](http://massive-js.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions/#the-db-directory) clarifies this issue. By default, the "db" folder should stay in the root directory of your project, and not where the scripts consuming the database are (in this case, "server/").

You must either move "db" to the root directory of your project (so as to be alongside "server", "public", etc.), or configure the `scripts` property to point to that location:

```
var massiveInstance = massive.connectSync({
  scripts: "server/db",
  connectionString
})
```